# Related Lists only in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

How to get only related lists using VF or  APEX, when we pass ID and object through URL, Ex suppose I send  Account Object and ID, I should be getting only Account object related lists but not Account details. if I use APEx:Detail I will get account and it’s related lists, but I want only related lists.

@Ivan here the code

controller

```
Public Class CustomRelatedList{


public String objectType {get; set;}

public Set<String>  chsobject1 {get;set;}
public sobjecttype chsobject {get;set;}

public sObject[] data {get; set;}


public CustomRelatedList() {
chsobject1 = new Set<String>(); 
 }


public void CustomRelatedList1() {
  //get URL parameters
```

//    objectType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('urlparm');

```
objectType = ‘Account’; //for testing purpose will get object type & Id from URL

Map<String , Schema.SObjectType> globalDescription =     Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

  Schema.sObjectType sObjType = globalDescription.get(objectType);  
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r1 = sObjType.getDescribe(); 

  List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = r1.getChildRelationships(); 

for (Schema.ChildRelationship C1:C) {
       chsobject = C1.getChildSObject(); 
     chsobject1.add(String.valueof(chsobject));
}

  }
}

 VF page
<apex:page controller="CustomRelatedList" >
<apex:repeat value="{!chsobject1}" var="a" >
<apex:relatedList list="{!a}" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" /> 
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

I want to display the all related List  for the Id(not just names) , but the parameter list takes only Literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cheat and hide the page block I don't want with CSS ;) It's not a clever Apex'y solution but it takes care of sooo much stuff (objects and lists the user is not supposed to see, page layout consistent with his profile and selected record type etc.)

Start with page like this:

```xml
<apex:page id="page" showHeader="false" readonly="true">
    <apex:pageMessage severity="error" strength="2" rendered="{!ISBLANK($CurrentPage.parameters.id)}"
        summary="Id not passed" />
    <apex:detail id="detail" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" 
        title="false" showChatter="false" relatedListHover="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

Inspect the created HTML, you should see something similar to this:

[image]

I'd just go and hide the `div`'s responsible for the "detail" part. I've decided to do it by the element's Id:

```xml
<apex:page id="page" showHeader="false" readonly="true">
    <style>
    div#ep_page_detail{
        display:none;
    }
    </style>

    <apex:pageMessage severity="error" strength="2" summary="Id not passed" rendered="{!ISBLANK($CurrentPage.parameters.id)}" />

    <apex:detail id="detail" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" 
        title="false" showChatter="false" relatedListHover="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

You might want to do it by class of that div or maybe classes of all child divs... Both options can break if SF changes the class names / method of the id generation. It's unlikely but just keep that in mind.

A more secure way to be sure the we know the Id that was generated would be to use the [`$Component`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm) global variable but it wasn't producing the right results when I've used `{!$Component.detail}`...

Comment: Cool :) Please consider accepting the answer in couple days time. That way you give few days more for other people to come with something clever but eventually it's good for the questions to go "off the radar".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `<apex:relatedList>` VF tag. See it's documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm).

Comment: thanks Ivan..suppose I am sending any generic object (it can be custom or standard object) and Id through URL and it should display only related Lists

Comment: You could use `DescribeSObjectResult.getChildRelationships()` in the controller to generate list of available relationships and then iterate over it on the page using `<apex:repeat>`

Comment: i was able to get child relationships, but when tries to display the related lists of these childs by using  <apex:repeat>  <apex:repeat value="{!childs}" var="a" >
 
    <apex:relatedList list="{!a}" subject="{!a}"/>
</apex:repeat>   it giving below error Error: Literal value is required for attribute list in <apex:relatedList>, is there any way to display these related lists

Comment: Please provide us with the Controller and VF code that you are using at the moment. Also consider doing it in a separate question if you feel like your original question was answered and you are now facing different problem.